# How do I navigate to the URL of a pages network request in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, automation, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am using Pupeteer to navigate to a page which makes a number of network requests.  If I see a network request that satisfies a condition I want to navigate to the url origin of that request and take a screenshot of the page that subseqently loads.

Here is my code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
    const prefix = "http://example.com/someprefix";
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setRequestInterception(true);
    page.on('request', async (request) => {
        if (request.url().startsWith(prefix)) {
            // Navigate to request.url() and take a screenshot of request.url()
        }
        return request.continue();
    })
    await page.goto("http://example.com", { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
    await browser.close();
})();
```

How do I achieve this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setRequestInterception(true);
    page.on('request', async (request) => {
        if (request.url().startsWith(prefix)) {
         const response = await page.goto(request.url());
         await page.waitForNavigation();
         await page.setViewport({ width: 1024, height: 800 });
         await page.screenshot({
         path: "./screenshot.jpg",
         type: "jpeg",
         fullPage: true
         });
        }
        return request.continue();
    })
    await page.goto("http://example.com", { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
    await browser.close();
    })();
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried putting a goto inside the page.on. I get: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Protocol error (Page.navigate): Target closed.

Comment: try add await request.abort(); and then goto logic.